# How can we get password of the system using java?

Tags: java, authentication, passwords, system

The  requirement is that ,I need windows userName and password as a application login userName and password.
So, any please tell me how to retrieve windows userName and password and how to use it in intranet application login userName and password.

Comment: If this were feasible, it would be a *huge* security problem.

Comment: In a windows domain environment to authenticate a logged on user with a web server on the same domain hosting an intranet site you would use *Integrated Windows Authentication* (ntlm/kerberos)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think that he is more interested in authenticating a user using his Windows credentials than getting the user's password in plain text.

Comment: @Lefteris008: Well, it depends on what the "intranet application login" requires... if that hasn't been integrated into Windows authentication, it could be tricky...

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, I assumed that the application employed the Windows Authentication System (Credential Manager etc.).

Comment: @Lefteris008: I just need to validate the the application login with those credentials not password in Plain text.Is there any way to do this??

Comment: @sajju As JonSkeet suggested, if this was possible for **every** application, then no password should be safe. You have to integrate your app using the Windows Authentication (ntlm/kerberos). Look at the duplicated question above and search for the Integrated Windows Authentication Framework.

Comment: @sajju _Clarifaction:_ if there was a simple API or library that would allow someone to send an encrypted password and then inform him that this password was *valid*, even though the system wouldn't return that password, someone may "sit in the middle" and store it at the time the user enters it in **plain text** and ensure that this is correct when the library sends the *OK* flag. In other words, the lib must be contained in a larger framework that would take care even for the password input. *That* is the Windows Authentication I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the system info using the `System.getProperties()` function like below.

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.list(System.out);
```

If you want a particular property like `username`, then you could do it like the following:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));
```

But as far as I'm aware, the system `password` is not available as a system property as it will be a massive security hole.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not read password.
you will get current user by `System.getProperty("user.name");`